# How to enclose null/Empty, single or multiple objects in array

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have an external API that sends data in any of 2 possible ways, like a single object or an array of objects. In both cases, I would expect to get the result in an array format.

```json
1.
{

  "PONumber": "1000445525",
  "POLineItem": "10",
  "NeedInDCDate": "10/08/2022",
  "SourceSystem": "o9LCT",
  "Region": "LSA"
} 

2.
[
{
  "PONumber": "1000445525",
  "POLineItem": "10",
  "NeedInDCDate": "10/08/2022",
  "SourceSystem": "o9LCT",
  "Region": "LSA"
},
{  "PONumber": "1000474525",
  "POLineItem": "10",
  "NeedInDCDate": "10/08/2022",
  "SourceSystem": "o9LCT",
  "Region": "LSE"
}
]
```

**Excepted output**

```json
1. 
[
{
  "PONumber": "1000445525",
  "POLineItem": "10",
  "NeedInDCDate": "10/08/2022",
  "SourceSystem": "o9LCT",
  "Region": "LSA"
}
]

2. 
[
{
  "PONumber": "1000445525",
  "POLineItem": "10",
  "NeedInDCDate": "10/08/2022",
  "SourceSystem": "o9LCT",
  "Region": "LSA"
},
{  "PONumber": "1000474525",
  "POLineItem": "10",
  "NeedInDCDate": "10/08/2022",
  "SourceSystem": "o9LCT",
  "Region": "LSE"

]
```

Please help with jolt spec

Comment: I tried this [

  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "[]"
    }
    }
          
]